# Is there any other RPG that includes snailmail-writing as an integral component?

Tags: game-recommendation, play-by-post

In [*De Profundis*](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/2029/de-profundis), an important part of the game is writing and sending letters to the other players. It's played in real-time with mail correspondence being the only form of contact between players. It's usually done by writing traditional snailmail for the sake of immersion.

This is the only game of that kind I've seen, but I'd like more alternatives. Any such game would do, but I suppose that free-form RPGs would better suited for this since the players can't make decisions very often. Is there any other?

I'm looking both for systems and scenarios to play with my friends.

Comment: It wasn't integral, and it was homebrew, hence not an answer, but a friend of mine had some success with a wiki. It was partially filled in, and various people had accounts in their characters' names, it was expanded by filling in mission reports, intel from sources and other such info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know of a similar game . . . or at least to my mind it is similar.  A fairly recent RPG by Daniel Solis called [Do: Pilgrims of the Flying Temple](http://danielsolisblog.blogspot.com/2007/08/do-pilgrims-of-flying-temple.html).  While not strictly "letters" per se, the players jointly use a journal to propel the action forward.

Comment: Daniel also wrote ["Happy Birthday, Robot!"](http://danielsolisblog.blogspot.com/2009/08/happy-birthday-robot.html)  and ["The Leftovers"](http://danielsolisblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/leftovers.html), which have similar mechanics, in that the players are writing the fiction, more than playing characters

Comment: +1@Colin.  Thanks for fleshing out Daniel's list of RPGs.  Sidenote: I supported Do: Pilgrims of the Flying Temple on Kickstarter and it was completely worth it.  Really like the mechanics of this game.

Comment: Do is not designed to be played by mail in any way similarly to De Profundis. It's a great game, but it's no more an answer to this question than any other of a thousand RPGs. A regretful -1.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is its called [De Profundis](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=84298) its really a very good game and can be quite spooky. I highly recommend it.

Similarly you can do "Blue Booking" via snail mail if it took your fancy good [thread can be found on RPG.net on the topic](http://forum.rpg.net/archive/index.php/t-104990.html)

Comment: Eponymous, welcome to RPG.SE. Unfortunately this particular answer does not actually address the question. The OP mentions De Profundis in his question and is looking for another similar game. Sorry about that. Anyways, welcome to our community and we hope you stick around. Please check out our [faq].

Comment: That link about bluebooking is great, even though it's not about a rules system the OP could adopt.